# Laravel php_my_admin

Tags: php, mysql, server, terminal, phpmyadmin

When I write PHP artisan in terminal of PHP_Storm in wont let me to access to PHP_my_admin . but if I stop server by control+C it let me.

I copy PHP_my_admin folder content into Ht_docs but it doesn't work yet. I do this in 127.0.0.1:8000. what is the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.